# Redirect after oauth authentication never happens with flask-oauth

Tags: python, oauth, flask

I'm using the Flask-Oauth add-on for Flask to authenticate with Twitter. I'm using essentially the exact code from the documentation but the redirect to go back to the index never appears to happen. Or, if it is happening, there's some weird browser caching going on.

My homepage basically looks like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    form = SadForm()
    if not g.user:
        needs_login = True
    else:
        # get some user stuff to display

    return render_template(...)
```

There's a button on that page that goes to a login view which matches the documentation:

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return twitter.authorize(callback=url_for('oauth_authorized',
        next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None))
```

The callback there is covered in this view:

```
@app.route('/oauth-authorized')
@twitter.authorized_handler
def oauth_authorized(response):
    next_url = request.args.get('next') or url_for('home')
    if response is None:
        flash(u'You denied the request to sign in.')
        return redirect(next_url)

    session['user_id'] = response['screen_name']
    current_user = g.db.users.find_one({'user_id': response['screen_name']})
    if current_user:
        user = current_user
    else:
        user = {}
    user['user_id'] = response['screen_name']
    user['twitter_token'] = response['oauth_token']
    user['twitter_secret'] = response['oauth_token_secret']
    g.user = user.copy()
    g.db.users.save(user)
    flash('You were signed in.')
    return redirect(next_url)
```

It appears that the redirect at the end of this method should "refresh" the view at `home` and because we've set `g.user` the user's content will be shown. However, in practice, the home page thinks no one is logged in, but if I use the browser button to refresh the page, it knows that I am logged in and presents the correct data.

The server logging looks like this:

```
21:39:36     INFO werkzeug - 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2012 21:39:36] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
21:39:45     INFO werkzeug - 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2012 21:39:45] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 302 -
21:39:47     INFO werkzeug - 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2012 21:39:47] "GET /oauth-authorized?oauth_token=nope&oauth_verifier=beep HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Notice there's no 200 for "GET /" after the 302 for `oauth-authorized`. Shouldn't there be?

Comment: The thread-local `g` object does not persist between requests unless you bootstrap it in a `before_request` view or some such. If you aren't doing that, the user object isn't going to be attached to `g`. However you say you're seeing the correct info upon refresh? So I'm assuming the above is happening appropriately. But I'm still a little confused, is the browser redirecting at all? You should see a request to the index, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a simple caching problem. In my `add_header` method which is decorated with `@app.after_request`, I made this change:

```
- response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=600' 
+ response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'public, max-age=0'
```

So, now the browser knows to re-fetch the index view every time. Ultimately, with a site on a larger scale, I'd change this pattern so I could use a cache effectively.